# Connect Apple Thunderbolt to Lenovo T420s

Tags: windows, thunderbolt-display

I have an Apple Thunderbolt Display 27 inch, Part MC914LL/A and I'd like to know if there is a way I could connect it to my Lenovo T420s ThinkPad.

[image: Cables]

[image]

Comment: Does the T420S has a Thunderbolt plug ?

Answer (score 1):

The cables in the top photo are of a MagSafe connector for an Apple laptop, (on the right,) and either a Thunderbolt or Apple DisplayPort connector, (on the left.)

The Lenovo has the standard VGA 15-pin and a DisplayPort (VESA) output which supports a single-link DVI-D 45J7915 cable. It is not compatible unless you can find a VESA DisplayPort to Apple Mini DisplayPort adaptor.

Perhaps the [Lenovo 45J7915 cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001F0QUWG) <> [M-M DVI-D cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045JNA18) <> [Apple Mini DisplayPort/DVI](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB570LL/B/mini-displayport-to-dvi-adapter) would work for you. I cannot predict if it will.

YMMV.